# magento ce 1.8 skus are not referenced on google

Tags: magento, hyperlink, sku

I have 1.5 m SKUs. 95% of these are available only via the search engine.
But Magento provides with human-readable URLs in a table for these. How can I get these to be refrenced by a search engine ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not seo expert but i can tell you that google can find your sku from product title like (https://www.google.co.in/search?num=100&dcr=0&source=hp&q=msf3&oq=msf3&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l3j0i10k1l2j0j0i10k1j0l3.1035.8066.0.8825.9.7.1.0.0.0.239.1490.0j2j5.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.8.1486.0..46j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i46i67k1j46i67k1j0i67k1j0i46k1.0.x5WP5gQnz0A) you need to append sku at the start or end of product page meta title.